# How can I make this function count the number of digits in a float?

Tags: python

I am creating a function that takes a number and prints the number of digits in the number. I have it working for ints but I want it to work for floats, too. I know it's simple but I am a beginner. I tried using `int(float(num))` but that produced an error (`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-f'`). I also tried using `.replace` but that didn't work. Any hints? Thank you

```
import sys

def digits(num):
    count = len(num)
    return count

num = sys.argv[1]
count = digits(num)
print(digits(num))
```

Comment: Where's the `-f` coming from? That's not a valid int either, unless you specify base 16 or higher.

Comment: Do you need to handle the exotic floats? i.e. `nan`, `inf`, and `-inf`

Comment: How do you define the number of digits of a float?

Comment: Strictly speaking, floats don't have digits, they have significant figures. For example, `1e+30` is represented with three numbers (one sig fig plus a two-digit mantissa), but as an int, it'd have 31 digits. So what should the code do in that situation?

Comment: @wjandrea That sounds odd. That float is represented like that by you, there, now. Other people, or even you somewhere/sometime else, can represent it differently...

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to work with `int` *or* `float` values. Strings representing numeric types are not the same as numeric types.

Comment: @Kelly I mean the canonical representation. If you put in `1e30` on the REPL, Python prints `1e+30`. Same for `float(10**30)`.

Comment: Correction: "a one-digit *mantissa* and a two-digit *exponent*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count how many values are in the number you can modify your code as follows (only for positive floats and integers)

```
count = len(num.replace('.', ''))
```

---

To work around with negative values you can use `json` module. It will cover you **mantisa case**.

```
import json
def count_digits(num):
    num = json.loads(num) # returns type bound value
    digit_str = str(abs(num)).replace('.', '')
    return len(digit_str)
```

Try:

```
my_float = '1e+30'
actual_float = json.loads(my_float)
print(type(actual_float)) # returns <class 'float'>
```

Notice: json.loads works only with string objects, so you're good to go with applying this function to your arguments as they are strings by default.

---

You can also use `re` module (regular expressions):

```
import re
def count_digits(num):
    return len(re.sub(fr'[.+-]', '', num))
```

Here you use re.sub to substitute `.`, `+`, and `-` sign for nothing and return the length of the resulting string.
Notice: with `re` module you're working with strings!

---

The last approach I can come up with is by using `eval` function

```
eval('-1e+15')
```

Comment: Thank you @Vladyslav ! I used the count = len(num.replace('.', '')) I had used something like that before but the syntax must have been wrong. It worked this time

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```py
def getDigitCount(input):
    s=str(abs(input))
    t=-1 if "." in s else 0
    return len(s) + t
```

Use it as follows

```py
getDigitCount(2312.5262627)
```

which yields to `11`. Notice, that this works for negative floats as well.

```py
getDigitCount(-2312.5262627)
```

which also yields to `11` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not working with int nor float it is all strings

So i would say you should subtract 1 to the count if there is a decimal point

Try this:

```
def digits(num):
    count = len(num) if '.' not in num else len(num) - 1
    return count
```